# how to check if a tree is complete?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

this is my class of A binary search tree:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

        class BSTNode {
                int data;
                BSTNode rchild;
                BSTNode lchild;

                //constructor
                public BSTNode(int n){
                        data=n;
                        lchild=rchild=null;

                }
        }

        private BSTNode root;
        private int size;

        public BinarySearchTree() {
                root = null;
                size = -1;
        }

        public boolean insert(int n) {
                if (root == null)
                        root = new BSTNode(n);
                else
                        insert(n, root);
                return true;
        }

        private void insert(int n, BSTNode r) {

                if (r.data > n)
                        if (r.lchild == null)
                                r.lchild = new BSTNode(n);
                        else
                                insert(n, r.lchild);
                else

                if (r.data < n)
                        if (r.rchild == null)
                                r.rchild = new BSTNode(n);
                        else
                                insert(n, r.rchild);


        }
}
```

Actually I am finding a difficulty in writing a method that checks if my tree is a Complete Binary Tree. Can someone provide me with the solution please.

I will follow this definition:
Complete binary tree : Every level except the last level is completely filled and all the nodes are left justified.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to modify this a bit for your your implementation of `BSTNode`, but I believe this should fit your needs. The basic idea is to recursively traverse the tree and make sure that the "complete" property is fulfilled for each subtree.

```
boolean checkBinaryTreeCompleteness(TreeNode root) {
  if (root != null) {
    if (root.right == null && root.left == null) {
      return true;
    }
    if (root.right != null && root.left != null) {
      return checkBinaryTreeCompleteness(root.left) && checkBinaryTreeCompleteness(root.right);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```